# How to upload a list of 5-digit zip codes to CartoDB?

Tags: carto, error, zip-codes, geocoding

I'm playing around with the free version of CartoDB right now. Trying to upload both a CSV and Excel document with a list of 5-digit zip codes. I have received a "there was a problem georeferencing your data" error. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: the free version of what?

Comment: Sorry, free version of CartoDB

Comment: Can you post some more information about this error?

Comment: All I get from CartoDB is "there was a problem georeferencing your data" and it directs me to contact support (this page right here).

Comment: it would help if you could provide a few lines (at least) of the file you are uploading, to see if others can replicate the problem or notice a problem with the source format.

Answer (score 1):

I just geocoded a couple zip codes without problem. Be sure that you:

- selected "You have a column identifying administrative regions" in the geocoding menu
- specified the correct column with the zip code in it (mine was a string data type column) where it says "In your table the polygons are identified by..."
- specify the United States in "I want my data in" and by "postal code"

If you're following these directions, I suggest trying a much smaller subset of your data, just a few zips and see if that works. There may be something weird in your data not visible to the naked eye (strange formatting always seems to get me).

Comment: Thank you, @Kevin. I did complete all those steps correctly. I used both string and number options. I will try uploading just a handful and see if it works.

Comment: figured out what the problem was-- the third step I got wrong. Thanks for your help!